# How to detect the Menu Listener in eclipse through plug-in development

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I developed a menu named MyMenu in eclipse as plug-in development.
I want to detect a listener as soon as we click on the MyMenu but I did not get any success while using/implementing MenuListener.
What is the way to achieve the same

Comment: An SWT Menu?  a MenuManager?  And then use it as a context menu?  Did you add it to the main menu bar?  Please add more of a description of what you tried, and what you were actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to create a Plug-in which creates Menu named MyMenu and add items inside it named MyMenuItem1....4 . But all these features I want to provide through SWT development not through plugin.xml. So how to achieve the same. 2ndly, If my eclipse have a Menu named MyMenu, so on click on this Menu, I want to receive a listener event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about adding a main menu item in a workbench window (similar to File or Edit) you cannot do it through SWT without breaking API.  3 options are available:

1) if you are writing an RCP app, you get to create the ActionBarAdvisor which gets first crack at filling in the main menu bar.  You use `MenuManagers` and `IContributionItems` to fill in the `MenuManagers`.  Both `ActionContributionItems` and `CommandContributionItems` are API.

2) Use plugin.xml and contribute to `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point.  You can contribute commands to it statically.  You can also use the *dynamic* element to contribute a `CompoundContributionItem`.  A `CompoundContributionItem` is called every time the menu is about to show, so that dynamic items (like the 4 most recently open files section in the File menu) can be added.  You can see some examples of this in the *org.eclipse.example.commands* plugin and matching presentation at https://github.com/paulweb515/commandsEclipseCon2011

3) use the `org.eclipse.ui.actionSets` extension point.  This is no longer under development, and is deprecated in Eclipse 4.x.